# Why my screen is flashing when i call the pros function - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

am making a slider, when i click on an item to slide to the second item, the screen flashs when the function is called ( the func that changes the items )

This comes exactly when  `clickAction();` is called.
Here is the demo : https://gfycat.com/ultimatetiredequestrian

PS: the click is handled in another file, here is some code :

```
const VerticalCarousel = ({ clickActionTransfer }) => {
        .
        ..
        ...
    
         <button
               data-glitch={item.type}
               type="button"
               onClick={clickActionTransfer}
               key={i}>
               CLICK
               {item.type}
         </button>
    };
```

This is my `<SLider/>` :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import VerticalCarousel from "./carousel/VerticalCarousel";

const Slider = ({ getData, idd, clickAction, children }) => {
  const [dataSlider, setDataSlider] = useState([]);
  const [displayTitleState, setDisplayTitleState] = useState(true);
  const [displayCarouselState, setDisplayCarouselState] = useState(true);

  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const [length, setLength] = useState(children.length);

  const handleSlideClick = () => {
    if (currentIndex < length - 1) {
      setCurrentIndex((prevState) => prevState + 1);
    }
    setDisplayCarouselState(false);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setDisplayTitleState(false);
      clickAction();
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setDisplayTitleState(true);
      setDisplayCarouselState(true);
    }, 2600);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setLength(children.length);
    setDataSlider(getData);
  }, [getData, children]);

  return (
    <div className="slider__container">
      {dataSlider.map((i) => {
        return (
          idd === i.id && (
            <div key={i.id}>
              <div
                style={{
                  transform: `translateX(-${currentIndex * 100}%)`,
                  display: "flex",
                  transition: "all .5s linear",
                }}
              >
                {" "}
                {children}{" "}
              </div>
              <div className="slider__content">
                <div
                  className={
                    "slider__left " + (i.theme === "light" ? "light-theme" : "")
                  }
                >
                  <div className="slider__progressBar">
                    {" "}
                    {i.progressBar.nb1}{" "}
                    <span className="slider__progressBar-lightTxt">
                      {" "}
                      {i.progressBar.nb1}
                    </span>{" "}
                    {i.progressBar.text}
                  </div>
                  <h1 className={displayTitleState ? "showTitle" : "hideTitle"}>
                    {" "}
                    {i.title}{" "}
                  </h1>
                </div>
                <div
                  className={`slider__right ${
                    displayCarouselState ? "showCarousel" : "hideCarousel"
                  } ${i.theme === "light" ? "light-theme" : ""}`}
                >
                  <VerticalCarousel
                    data={i.slider}
                    clickActionTransfer={handleSlideClick}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Slider;
```

App.js :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Slider from "./Slider";
import "./App.scss";

function App() {
  const [loadSlide, setLoadSlide] = useState(0);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const handleclick = () => {
    setLoadSlide(loadSlide + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoadSlide((loadSlide) => loadSlide + 1);
    fetch("/data.json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setData(json.lvmh.sliders);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className={
          "slider " +
          (loadSlide >= 1 &&
            loadSlide <= data.length &&
            loadSlide + 1 &&
            `ifSlider`)
        }
      >
        <>
          {loadSlide >= 0 && loadSlide <= data.length && loadSlide + 1 && (
            <Slider clickAction={handleclick} idd={loadSlide} getData={data}>
              {data.map((img) => {
                return (
                  <img className={"slider__bg---- "} src={img.img} alt="" />
                );
              })}
            </Slider>
          )}
        </>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it, i don't know why but the bug comes from the browser console when it's opened ! weird !